# ListView with TextView and Buttons

Tags: android, listview

My `ListView` consists of three `TextViews`, say T1, T2 and T3. I also have two buttons, B1 and B2

I want them to Appear like this:

B1 [Space Between Buttons] B2
T1
T2
T3

The T1 etc are on screen under the buttons and not just under B1.

Below is my xml which I tried to change as per many answers to questions on SO.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Left Button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Right Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hadithView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone please help.
Thank you

**EDIT** 
I am using `CursorAdapter` to populate the views. The B1 and B2 are repeated with `TextViews`. I would like to keep B1 and B2 on top(fixed) and be able to scroll the text views(without their own buttons)

**EDIT 2**
I fixed the Buttons issue. Though I need two buttons fixed at the top too. I removed them and now have two buttons attached with text views which is what I do need later on anyway.

Now The Text is being imposed on each other.

Here is my new xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/engText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="serif"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/arabText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:typeface="sans"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/refText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a very quick fix - but it gives what you want. Basically: Your list view is taking over the whole screen - and you dont' t seem to need it according to your question. You can use a ListView at the top with an empty TextView as your "space" but then you have to give the TextViews below attributes as to where they should be placed in the RelativeLayout (your main layout). I have quickly added attributes with respect to the LinearLayout (for the first TextView) and then with respect to the above TextView for all below. You can do it differently - and in general, I think, you should look up the documentation for xml files in android and/or just play around a bit. It is all pretty logical, but I also struggled when I started. Here is my code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Left Button"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:text="Right Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linLay"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="My dummy text"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="My dummy text"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="My dummy text"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
Can you please have a look at my edit to OP.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `RelativeLayout` and keep different sections in different `RelativeLayout` relative to each other and use its attribute `layout_below`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    //give some id
    android:id="@+id/one">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Left Button"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Right Button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@+id/one">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/engText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:typeface="serif"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/arabText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/refText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/hadithView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should use LinearLayout and not RelativLayout.
Because the order of your items are just linear vertical ordered.
Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Left Button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Right Button"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="T1"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="T2"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:text="T3"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hadithView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
This works partly. Buttons are repeated with Text Views and two stay at top(fixed). Right now I would like to have only top two buttons. 
Please see my EDIT to OP

Comment: maybe you should think about to use the toolbar to do like stuff which is always fixed on top? If not then maybe an explizit ScollView can help you.

Comment: : ) I am coming from `WebView`. My app was almost ready but then `WebView` showed is defect(too slow to load big html data). So I came to `Listview` hoping it will be faster. It is my first app. 
Let see how this view goes. 

Thank you for your suggestions : )

Answer (score 0):

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Left Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Right Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Doing this will set the two buttons next to each other, and then you can place all under elements under this linearlayout.

**Changes made:**

- LinearLayout orientation changed to horizontal
- Linearlayout holds weigthSum of 1
- layout_width of both buttons set to wrap_content (They will still hold their place because of 0.5 weight - so they both split the view.

[image: Button layout]

If you want more space between buttons put som margin on the left button like this.

```
android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. 
This is my xml that I used with the `CursorAdapter`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/engText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="serif"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/arabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/refText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:textSize="15sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my `Activity` xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/hadView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you everyone who responded.